# Django: make model field and foreign key unique together

Tags: django, validation, django-models, unique

I have the following model:

```
class Locale (models.Model):
    """
    Locale model
    """
    locale_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    locale_name = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    magister = models.ForeignKey(Magister, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_name(self):
        return self.locale_name
```

In the database, there must be exactly one locale-magister pair.

To create each locale item, an administrator has to upload the locales. This is done via a bulk upload:

```
try:
    lcl=Locale(locale_name = data_dict["locale_name"], magister = data_dict["magister "])
    # lcl.full_clean()
    locales_list.append(lcl)
    rows+=1
    if rows==INSERTNUMBER:
        try:         
            Locale.objects.bulk_create(locales_list) 
            locales_uploaded+=rows
        except IntegrityError as e:
            print("Error: locale bulk_create "+repr(e))                            
        locales_list=[]
        rows=0
```

I tried using `lcl.full_clean()` in my bulk upload but I get a `UNIQUE constraint failed: zones_locale.locale_name` error and only about 1/2 of all locales upload successfully.

I also tried using:

```
def validate_unique(self, exclude=None):
    lcl = Locale.objects.filter(locale_id=self.locale_id)
    if lcl.filter(magister=self.magister).exists():
        raise ValidationError("item already exists")
```

But the same error occurs.

I also tried using:

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = (("locale_name", "magister"),)
```

This did not work either.

From what I can tell, the problem is that there exist locales with the same name that belong to different magisters.

How can I allow locales with the same name to be uploaded while also enforcing the uniqueness of any given locale-magister pair?

Comment: How can you get a `UNIQUE contraint failed` on the column `locale_name` if your model doesn't have that constraint? Are you sure your DB reflects your model? (i.e. did you makemigrations and migrate?)

Comment: `unique_together` should work by the way, if you've migrated correctly.

Comment: `unique_together()` only works for the field of the same model, it does not work with related field.

Comment: Yes, I ran both python manage.py makemigrations and migrate - these results were after running both